FluxCD fails to send notifications to Slack
I am trying to send the notifications to Slack. I set the Provider and the Alert. The secret map has the token, and I can use it to send messages within a container using curl, but flux fails to send notifications.
The token, namespace, alert, and provider look correct.
I found this error message in the Alert resource:
Warning  NotificationDispatchFailed  11m (x14 over 2d3h)  notification-controller  failed to send notification for Kustomization/tenant/apps: postMessage failed: failed to execute request: context deadline exceeded

Any idea or suggestion??
Tahnks.
